# How can I reference a Structure in a Structure using python ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, structure, ctypes

Good morning,
I have been searching for an answer for quite some time. I hope I simply didn't try the wrong key words. Thanks for the answers! Here is my question:

I'm writing some proof of concept code. I have two C structs. StructureA has a pointer to StructureB. The function bar prints the values to the console. The goal is to initialize and use the structs in Python and pass them to a shared lib, which does some fancy stuff with the structs.

I assume I do something wrong in Python. I tried several ways, as you can see in the (Python-)main function.

Additionally the content of the Strings is mixed up, but that is not my major questions.

This is my C code:

```
#define _DLL_H_ 
#if BUILDING_DLL 
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport) 
#else /* Not BUILDING_DLL */ 
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport) 
#endif /* Not BUILDING_DLL */ 

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct StructureB {
    int Value1;
    char Value2[80];
} StructureB;

typedef struct StructureA {
    int ValueA;
    char ValueB[80];
    StructureB *ValueC;
} StructureA;

void bar(StructureA *ref){
    printf("ValueA: %d\n", ref->ValueA);
    printf("ValueB: %s\n", ref->ValueB);
    printf("Value1: %d\n", ref->ValueC->Value1);
    printf("Value2: %s\n", ref->ValueC->Value2);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Here is my Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ctypes import *
import sys

class StructureB(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('Value1', c_int),
               ('Value2', c_char_p)]

class StructureA(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('ValueA', c_int),
               ('ValueB', c_char_p),
               ('ValueC', POINTER(StructureB))]


def main(argv):
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("structures.dll")

    sub_struct = StructureB()
    sub_struct.Value1 = 42*42
    sub_struct.Value2 = c_char_p("Hello StructureB!")

    struct = StructureA()
    struct.ValueA = -42
    struct.ValueB = c_char_p("Hello StructureA!")

    #struct.ValueC = pointer(sub_struct)
    #struct.ValueC = cast(sub_struct, POINTER(StructureB))
    #struct.ValueC = addressof(StructureB)
    #struct.ValueC = pointer(StructureB)
    struct.ValueC = StructureB

    lib.bar(pointer(struct))

    print sub_struct.Value2
    print struct.ValueB

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: An array is not a pointer. The fields should be `('Value2', c_char * 80)` and `('ValueB', c_char * 80)`. The assignments should be `sub_struct.Value2 = "Hello StructureB!"`, `struct.ValueB = "Hello StructureA!"`, and `struct.ValueC = pointer(sub_struct)`.

Comment: Also, you can load the library with `lib = CDLL("structures")` instead of `lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("structures.dll")`. It's more efficient to use `byref` to pass an argument by reference, e.g. `lib.bar(byref(struct))`. For type safety set `lib.bar.argtypes = (POINTER(StructureA),)`.